# Drive not ready condition while DVD media inserted. Why does this happen?

Tags: c#, driveinfo

I have this code:

```
DriveInfo dr = new DriveInfo(@"E:\");

if (dr.IsReady == false)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Drive E: is not ready. Please insert a blank DVD medium.");
}
```

So, I insert a blank DVD in the drive and run the code. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What happens when you insert a DVD that has information on it?

Comment: Try `DriveInfo dr = new DriveInfo("E");`

Comment: @Sparky - You do understand that DriveInfo will not provide you the means to burn a disk right?

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes iam aware of this thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DriveInfo.IsReady` on the blank DVD will return false.

If you need to distinguish if a blank disc is there, you'll need to use a different library. Here is a program that includes a interop wrapper around IMAPI2 (Window's  Image Mastering API): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx

Use the interop wrapper and call

```
IDiscFormat2Data discFormatData = new MsftDiscFormat2Data();
if (discFormatData.CurrentMediaStatus == IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE.IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I only need to know that the media inserted in my drive is a DVD can i accomplish this without utilizing IMAPI?

Comment: Well apparently the drive is "ready" when there is a formatted/mounted (i.e. non-blank) disc in it that it can read...